# Preventing the same random output in a row

Tags: java

My code is simply supposed to ask a question but I would like to prevent it from asking the same random question twice.

```
public static String askQuestion(){
    if (hasMoreQuestions() == true);{
        int oldq = 
        String[] Question = {"How are you today?","Do you enjoy the rain?","Meow?"};
        Random randomno = new Random();
        int nextq = randomno.nextInt(3);
        if (oldq == nextq){
            askQuestion();
        }
        oldq = nextq;

        return Question[nextq];
    }
}
```

That is my attempt i'm hoping to simply compare the previous output to the randomly chosen new output. But i'm new to Java and am having trouble with figuring out what the best method to achieve this would be.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269071/how-to-avoid-returning-the-same-string-twice-in-a-row     This post will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to realize that by interfering with the normal distribution, you're not asking "random" questions. Blah, blah, purist nonsense dealt with. We all know what you mean: you want to present questions drawn randomly from some pool, that pool not including the most recently-asked question. 
That suggests a very simple approach approach: draw a random question from the set and present it to the user. Remove it from the set and store it as `previousQuestion`. Restore it to the pool after asking the nextQuestion (which of course becomes the previousQuestion) and so forth. 
This is much easier to achieve if you use a Set of some sort rather than an array.

However, if you're keen to use an array, then you could get away with something like this (only adding the parts you don't already know):

```
int prevQuestion = -1;
int nextQuestion = -1;
while (continuing) {
  while (nextQuestion == prevQuestion) {
    nextQuestion = randomno.nextInt(questions.length);
  }
  prevQuestion = nextQuestion;
  // ask nextQuestion and prompt to see if we're continuing
}
```

Comment: Setting the values within the loops without having them being overwritten or ignored was illuding me. This worked great, thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. You should consider looking into Sets (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) as they're really well suited to this sort of problem (and also sets are pretty fundamental, mathematically)

Answer (score 3):

### 1st attempt

You can try checking for different numbers, then just print the question at those number indexes instead of calling the same function recursively, for example:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class UniqueRandom {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int n1, n2;

        n1 = r.nextInt(3);
        do {
            n2 = r.nextInt(3);
        } while (n2 == n1);

        String question[] = {"How are you today?","Do you enjoy the rain?","Meow?"};

        System.out.println(question[n1]);
        System.out.println(question[n2]);
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
How are you today?
Do you enjoy the rain?
```

---

### 2nd attempt

Another way is using a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), where you keep unique keys, and remove elements once you have printed them, for example:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class UniqueRandom {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int n1, n2;
        String question[] = {"How are you today?","Do you enjoy the rain?","Meow?"};
        HashMap <Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        String q = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
            map.put(i, question[i]); //Filling the map
        }

        do {
            n1 = r.nextInt(question.length);
            while (!map.containsKey(n1)) {
                n1 = r.nextInt(question.length);
            }
            q = map.get(n1);
            System.out.println(q); //Print the question
            map.remove(n1); //Remove it from set
        } while (map.size() > 0);
    }
}
```

This will **ALWAYS** print a unique combination, w/o repeating questions.

```
How are you today?
Do you enjoy the rain?
Meow?
```